# Moving Excel document breaks hyperlinks URL format

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, microsoft-office-2013

Scenario: I am creating an Excel spreadsheet with file locations and using hyperlinks to open either the file or directory it is stored in.

Problem: I noticed when I hyperlinked a file it used `..\..\` in the URL which had me concerned it was a relative path and I don't want that. I tried moving the Excel file and the hyperlinks to doc's don't open anymore. (Excel say's "Can't Open the specified File").

Setup: Office 2013 w/ Win 7 Pro

Steps to Replicate:

- Create an Excel Document and Hyperlink a Word Document
- Confirm opening Word Doc via Hyperlink works as expected
- Save Excel Document
- Move it to new Location
- Try to re-open Hyperlink

Notes:

- I noticed the URL literally changed when I cut and pasted the file from an absolute path (which I manually entered) to a relative path full of `%` and `../` etc.

Comment: [Hyperlinks - absolute path and non relative](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/689145-hyperlinks-absolute-path-non-relative.html)

Comment: Will test, tried googling myself but must have used wrong keywords, thanks @DavidPostill

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried that but it didn't seem to work